# DB2 Insertion failing in a batch program (using Java and DB2)

Tags: java, db2, batch-processing

This is the first time I am using DB2 as Database with my Java application. I am writing a batch program and I need to insert into multiple parent - child tables.

The issue I am facing is that the insert into the table is failing giving me the following error:

```
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][3.59.81] Batch failure.
The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. 
ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null
                    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:404)
                    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.o.a(o.java:365)
                    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cn.a(cn.java:4280)
                    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cn.c(cn.java:4063)
                    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.l.c(l.java:78)
                    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cn.executeBatch(cn.java:2425)
```

Apart from this error I am not able to find any other error in any of my log files. Kindly provide me some pointers to trace or fix this issue.

Comment: Have you searched for the error code -4229 in DB2 forums?

Comment: Your use of the phrase "batch program" leads me to ask, what platform your program is running on?

Answer (score 3):

There are nested exception, and the exception that you are catching is the "top" one. You have to scan the other exceptions via the getNextException in order to detect the error. This is a normal behaviour while using JDBC.

I advise you to have a "while" in the catch part of your method, in order to found the error.